# Tikz: Too large dimension for radar graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have a radar graph like below, however, I am not sure why I am facing "too large dimension" error.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{filecontents}
% the filecontents environment writes its content to the specified file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
c1     c2     c3  c4
i1     21     26  53
i2     38     10  52
i3     81     1   18
i4     63     0   37
i5     63     0   37
i6     34     0   66
i7     62     0   38
i8     40     0   60
i9     53     0   47
i10    54     0   46
i11    61     0   39
i12    15     3   82
i13    83     1   16
i14    41     2   57
i15    77     0   23
i16    100    0   0
i17    72     0   28
i18    66     0   34
i19    86     0   14
i20    81     0   19
i21    32     0   68
i22    49     0   51
i23    25     1   74
i24    88     0   12
i25    48     3   49
i26    87     0   13
i27    48     0   52
i28    92     0   8
i29    43     0   57
i30    60     0   40
i31    60     0   40
i32    33     0   67
i33    26     0   74
i34    70     0   30
i35    95     0   5
i36    0      0   100
i37    43     0   57
i38    27     0   73
i39    67     0   33
i40    26     0   74
i41    20     0   80
i42    21     0   79
i43    22     0   78
i44    16     0   84
i45    99     0   1
i46    55     0   45
i47    25     0   75
i48    28     0   72
i49    13     0   87
i50    23     0   77
i51    9      0   91
i52    7      0   93
i53    5      0   95
i54    0      0   100
i55    { }    0   100
i56    { }    0   10
i57    { }    0   68
i58    { }    0   84
i59    { }    0   90
i60    { }    0   93
i61    { }    0   91
i62    { }    0   100
i63    { }    0   100
i64    { }    0   100
i65    { }    0   100
i66    { }    0   100
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagramFromFile[
        scale=0.5,
        label distance=.5cm,
        gap     = 10, label space=3,  
        lattice = 100]{data.dat}
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = green,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = green,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = green!20]{data.dat}{3} 
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = blue,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = blue,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = blue!20]{data.dat}{2}
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = red,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = red,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = red!20]{data.dat}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You get `dimension too large` error because your diagram is way too large. Even with `scale=0.05` and `gap = 2`, it steps out of the paper. Your datas are already big, and your scaling make them enormous.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any way to resolve this problem (e.g., by transforming the values)?

Answer (score 5):

Slightly adjusting the parameters and commenting out the last `tkzKiviatLineFromFile` command, which caused too many `treated as zero` errors, I got the following picture:
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{filecontents}
% the filecontents environment writes its content to the specified file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
c1     c2     c3  c4
i1     21     26  53
i2     38     10  52
i3     81     1   18
i4     63     0   37
i5     63     0   37
i6     34     0   66
i7     62     0   38
i8     40     0   60
i9     53     0   47
i10    54     0   46
i11    61     0   39
i12    15     3   82
i13    83     1   16
i14    41     2   57
i15    77     0   23
i16    100    0   0
i17    72     0   28
i18    66     0   34
i19    86     0   14
i20    81     0   19
i21    32     0   68
i22    49     0   51
i23    25     1   74
i24    88     0   12
i25    48     3   49
i26    87     0   13
i27    48     0   52
i28    92     0   8
i29    43     0   57
i30    60     0   40
i31    60     0   40
i32    33     0   67
i33    26     0   74
i34    70     0   30
i35    95     0   5
i36    0      0   100
i37    43     0   57
i38    27     0   73
i39    67     0   33
i40    26     0   74
i41    20     0   80
i42    21     0   79
i43    22     0   78
i44    16     0   84
i45    99     0   1
i46    55     0   45
i47    25     0   75
i48    28     0   72
i49    13     0   87
i50    23     0   77
i51    9      0   91
i52    7      0   93
i53    5      0   95
i54    0      0   100
i55    { }    0   100
i56    { }    0   10
i57    { }    0   68
i58    { }    0   84
i59    { }    0   90
i60    { }    0   93
i61    { }    0   91
i62    { }    0   100
i63    { }    0   100
i64    { }    0   100
i65    { }    0   100
i66    { }    0   100
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagramFromFile[
        scale=0.2,
        label distance=.5cm,
        gap     = 10pt, label space=3pt,  
        lattice = 100pt]{data.dat}
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = green,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = green,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = green!20]{data.dat}{3} 
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = blue,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = blue,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = blue!20]{data.dat}{2}
%\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
%                       color      = red,
%                       mark       = ball,
%                       ball color = red,
%                       mark size  = 4pt,
%                       fill       = red!20]{data.dat}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```